# Flashcard app in Golang

Tags: game, console, go

Most of my development experience is in the .NET world. I started learning Golang again a few months ago, and decided to build a super simple flashcard app.

This project was mainly to get used to golang syntax, some common idiosyncrasies and conventions, improve my ability to locate code smells etc.

The code is split into two code files, and reads data from a txt file (I have provided a sample file for reference).

I am trying to improve my Golang programming skills (and wider programming skills in general), so please let me know if I can make any improvements.

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

const FlashcardFilePath = "flashcards.txt"

type Flashcard struct {
    Definition string
    Answer     string
}

type UserFlashcard struct {
    Definition string
    Answer     string
    UserAnswer string
}

func main() {
    quit := false

    for !quit {
        //Flashcards should be loaded on each menu "tick"
        flashcards := GetFlashcards()
        switch GetMenuItem() {
        case 1:
            CreateFlashcard()
        case 2:
            PracticeFlashcards(flashcards)
        case 3:
            DisplayFlashcards(flashcards)
        case 4:
            quit = true
        }
    }
}

func CreateFlashcard() {
    fmt.Println()
    definition := GetUserInput("Definition: ")
    answer := GetUserInput("Answer: ")
    WriteFlashcardToFile(Flashcard{
        Definition: definition,
        Answer:     answer,
    })
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("Flashcard created")
    fmt.Println()
}

func GetFlashcards() []Flashcard {
    stream := string(ReadFlashcardStreamFromFile())
    return ParseFlashcardsFromString(stream)
}

func PracticeFlashcards(flashcards []Flashcard) {
    numberOfQuestions, err := strconv.Atoi(strings.Trim(GetUserInput("Enter the number of questions you would like: "), "\r\n"))
    var correctFlashcards []Flashcard
    var incorrectFlashcards []UserFlashcard

    HandleError(err)

    if numberOfQuestions == 0 {
        return
    }

    for i := 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++ {
        randomFlashcard := flashcards[rand.Intn(len(flashcards))]
        result, answer := AskQuestion(randomFlashcard)
        if result {
            correctFlashcards = append(correctFlashcards, randomFlashcard)
        } else {
            incorrectFlashcards = append(incorrectFlashcards, ConvertFlashcardToUserFlashcard(randomFlashcard, answer))
        }
    }

    ShowGameReport(correctFlashcards, incorrectFlashcards)
}

func ConvertFlashcardToUserFlashcard(flashcard Flashcard, userAnswer string) UserFlashcard {
    return UserFlashcard {
        Answer: flashcard.Answer,
        Definition: flashcard.Definition,
        UserAnswer: userAnswer,
    }
}

///This returns whether the user correctly answered the question or not
func AskQuestion(flashcard Flashcard) (bool, string) {
    fmt.Println("Definition: ", flashcard.Definition)
    userAnswer := GetUserInput("Answer: ")
    return CheckAnswer(flashcard.Answer, userAnswer), userAnswer
}

func CheckAnswer(correctAnswer string, userAnswer string) bool {
    return strings.EqualFold(strings.TrimSpace(correctAnswer), strings.TrimSpace(userAnswer))
}

func ShowGameReport(correctFlashcards []Flashcard, incorrectFlashcards []UserFlashcard) {
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("~~~~~~~~~~Report~~~~~~~~~~")
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("You got ", len(correctFlashcards), " correct and ", len(incorrectFlashcards), " incorrect.")
    if len(correctFlashcards) > 0 {
        fmt.Println("~~~Correct Answers~~~")
        for _, correct := range correctFlashcards {
            fmt.Println("   Definition: ", correct.Definition)
            fmt.Println("   Answer: ", correct.Answer)
        }
    }
    if len(incorrectFlashcards) > 0 {
        fmt.Println("~~~Incorrect answers~~~")
        for _, incorrect := range incorrectFlashcards {
            fmt.Println("   Definition: ", incorrect.Definition)
            fmt.Println("   Answer: ", incorrect.Answer)
            fmt.Println("   Your answer: ", incorrect.UserAnswer)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println()
}

func DisplayFlashcards(flashcards []Flashcard) {
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ F L A S H C A R D S ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    for _, card := range flashcards {
        fmt.Println(" ")
        for i := 0; i < 25-len(card.Definition); i++ {
            //Formatting - pad left
            fmt.Print(" ")
        }
        fmt.Printf(card.Definition)
        fmt.Print(" means ", card.Answer)
    }
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    fmt.Println()
    GetUserInput("Finished?")
}

func GetMenuItem() int {
    PrintMenu()
    input := GetUserInput("Numeric option: ")
    option, err := strconv.Atoi(input[0:1])
    HandleError(err)
    return option
}

func PrintMenu() {
    fmt.Println("=======================")
    fmt.Println("        M E N U        ")
    fmt.Println("=======================")
    fmt.Println("1. Create new flashcard")
    fmt.Println("2. Practice flashcard")
    fmt.Println("3. Display all flashcards")
    fmt.Println("4. Quit program")
}

func ReadFlashcardStreamFromFile() []byte {
    file, err := os.Open(FlashcardFilePath)
    HandleError(err)
    defer file.Close()
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    return b
}

func ParseFlashcardsFromString(input string) []Flashcard {
    lines := strings.Split(input, ",")
    var flashcards []Flashcard
    for line := 0; line < len(lines)-1; line++ {
        flashcards = append(flashcards, ParseSingleFlashcard(lines[line]))
    }
    return flashcards
}

func ParseSingleFlashcard(input string) Flashcard {
    parts := strings.Split(input, "|")
    if parts != nil && len(parts) > 0 {
        return Flashcard{
            Definition: strings.TrimSpace(parts[0]),
            Answer:     strings.TrimSpace(parts[1]),
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Error: empty string was passed into ParseSingleFlashcard")
    var f Flashcard
    return f
}

func WriteFlashcardToFile(flashcard Flashcard) {
    text := BuildFlashcardString(flashcard)
    AppendLineToFile(FlashcardFilePath, text)
}

func BuildFlashcardString(flashcard Flashcard) string {
    return flashcard.Definition + " | " + flashcard.Answer + ","
}

func AppendLineToFile(filepath string, line string) {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filepath, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    HandleError(err)
    _, err = fmt.Fprintln(f, line)
    HandleError(err)
    err = f.Close()
    HandleError(err)
}
```

**utility.go**

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func GetUserInput(promptText string) string {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print(promptText)
    input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    return input
}

func HandleError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(2)
    }
}
```

**Flashcards.txt**

```
Heiße
 | Hot
,
Frei
 | Free
,
Flugzeug
 | Airplane
,
Essen
 | Food
,
Spielzeug
 | Toy
,
```